# Segmentation fault when running forge init

Tags: foundry, forge, vscode

I got the "Segmentation fault" when I tried to run the command "forge init".chatgpt answer is
"A Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that "does not belong to you." It's a mechanism that prevents you from corrupting the memory and introducing hard-to-debug memory bugs. Whenever you get a segmentation fault, you know you are doing something wrong with memory - such as accessing a variable that has already been freed or writing to a read-only portion of memory".

I understand it was something related to memory but I do not know how to rectify it anyone help me rectify it

Comment: It means your software is broken, has a bug and must be fixed. Usually these kind of issues can be only dealt by having a repeatable steps to repeat the issue with known software version numbers and then reporting this issue to the software authors as technically as possible.

Comment: where i have to report this issue?

Comment: Foundry Github.